# want to move .so library files to another folder after compiled by pyinstaller

Tags: python, hyperlink, compilation, runtime, pyinstaller

### env: linux, python2.6, pyinstaller2.0

### target: to specify where to find the .so libs after compiled / moved to other folder

I use to compile my server side python source code using

```
pyinstaller -F --noconsole --out=/bala /bala.py
```

but this requires to extract the packed .so to system

```
/tmp/_MEI*
```

when run the all in one exe, which is not allowed, so I just remove the '-F' tag, to be

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --out=/bala /bala.py
```

this works fine, but all .so files were at the same folder with the binary program, like libpython or zlib,

I somehow prefer the layout to be

```
root/exe/my_program
root/lib/all_so_lib
```

obviously, the .so are no longer at it's '.' folder

as expected, It does not work by default, says

```
Python library not found
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATHONLIB, PATHONPATH, and even PATH, both not work.

Here I want to ask if this is possible, if so, how?, to specify environment variable at runtime, or to add some parameter when freeze the code? I'm just a normal user and has no rights to touch /usr/lib/